# Loading fine-tuned MobileNetV3 ConvNet in STM32CubeAI

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I loaded my mobilenetv3 model in STM32CubeAI but when I tried to choose the compression ratio of 4 and 8 to reduce size, the RAM and FLASH requirements are still the same.

Also, I optimized my model in tensorflow lite which results in ~2MB, but when I load it into STM32CubeAI, it still reads the original size which is 6MB?

Please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with STM32CubeAI's compression. What specifically does it do? If it's just a lossless compressor for the finished network, then of course the compressed network will be uncompressed when used, so you can't reduce the RAM usage that way. Flash requirements might be dominated by other factors. When you say "I optimized my model … which results in ~2MB": 2 MB of what, specifically? This sounds like a pretty giant model to me.

Comment: I just used tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE, then the model shrinks in size from 6MB to 2MB. but  STM32CubeAI still reads the model as 6MB.

Comment: That thing does exactly nothing: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Optimize